# Wondering if actions can be invoked by webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I understand that API.AI works when intents being triggered and responses through a client like Google assistant. I am just wondering if it can subscribe to a certain event and gets triggered.
Basically, I am trying to find out how my server can send me a message when a certain event occurs (e.g., When weather changes from rainy to sunny, I want my chatbot let me know even if I did not ask)

Answer (score 0):

Actions on Google does not support notifications or events. Right now, at least, it is request-response only, in the same way a web server works (which is why webhooks work so well for it).